# Playwright headless tests are slower than headful tests

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, playwright, headless

Playwright headless tests are supposed to be faster than the headful tests. My headful tests are taking ~17sec and headless ones are taking ~1min.

Looking into the problem, I saw that in headless mode, the chrome might be running without gpu acceleration and I should force enable gpu acceleration through flags like

```
--use-gl="swiftshader"
--enable-unsafe-webgpu
--ignore-gpu-blacklist
```

I tried all of them, none of them seems to work. Do someone know the solution? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?